# SQL Group By then put values n their own column in new record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pivot

Im trying to make an SQL view that returns players in a team. I have gotten as far as returning results like this.

```
Team      | Person
--------------------
Red Team  | Jack
Red Team  | Jill
Red Team  | Harry
Blue Team  | Bob
Blue Team  | Benny
Blue Team  | Brian
```

How can I group by the team and select each of the people in that team and put them into their own column? So the desired results would be something like this.

```
Team       | Person | Person | Person |
---------------------------------------
Red Team   | Jack     Jill     Harry
Blue Team  | Bob      Benny    Brian
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Look up pivot and unpibot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

To identify each person, i have used `row_number()` function and then used them in case statement.

```
declare @tab table
(
    team varchar(50),
    Person varchar(50)
)

Insert into @tab
    values ('Red Team', 'Jack'),
            ('Red Team', 'Jill'),
            ('Red Team', 'Harry'),
            ('Blue Team', 'Bob'),
            ('Blue Team', 'Banny'),
            ('Blue Team', 'Brian')

SELECT 
    Team,
    MAX(case when PersonKey = 1 then Person end) Person,
    MAX(case when PersonKey = 2 then Person end) Person,
    MAX(case when PersonKey = 3 then Person end) Person
From 
(
        Select Team, 
         Person, 
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By team Order By Person) as PersonKey 
        From @tab
 ) t 
Group By Team
```

**Result**

```
Team        Person  Person  Person
----------------------------------
Blue Team   Banny   Bob     Brian
Red Team    Harry   Jack    Jill
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ill try it now

Comment: You legend, this works like a charm. Thank you so much!